# How to find the approximate value of $\operatorname{arcosh}$?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, approximation, hyperbolic-functions

Does anyone knows a good way to approximate $\operatorname{arcosh}$ between $1.0$ and $1.1$ precisely? Me and some others are using the standard series $$\ln(2x)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)\frac{x^{-2n}}{2n}$$ but but between $1.0$ and $1.1$ it's only precise to about $2$ decimal places, which isn't enough.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with just $\operatorname{arcosh} = \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$?  There will be some cancellation when $x \approx 1$ but not so bad that you'll only get 2 decimals.

Comment: Just to supplement the @emacsdrivesmenuts comment: for small $\epsilon>0$,$$\operatorname{arcosh}(1+\epsilon)=\operatorname{arsinh}\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}.$$

Comment: The "standard" series you post is NOT an approximation. It's exactly equal to $\text{arcosh}(x)$ for all $x\ge 1$. It's not precise only about $2$ decimal places, is has *all* the decimal places correct. **IF** you take only a few summands of the series (you didn't tell us how you used the **exact** formula to produce the approximation) then you may get a bad approximation, but then you could take more terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a very accurate approximation
$$\cosh ^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1) ^n\, a_n\,t^{2n+1}\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\sqrt{2 (x-1)}$$ where the first $a_n$ form the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{24},\frac{3}{640},\frac{5}{7168},\frac{35}{294912},\frac{63}{288358
   4},\frac{231}{54525952},\frac{143}{167772160},\cdots\right\}$$

We can transform the series in $t$ into a simple Padé approximant which, back to $x$ would give
$$\cosh ^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{2(x-1)}\, \frac{ 17 x+103}{27 x+93}$$ whose error is
$\frac{61 (x-1)^{7/2}}{22400 \sqrt{2}}$ that is to say $6.09\times 10^{-7}$.

**Edit**

A much better one would be
$$\cosh ^{-1}(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2(x-1)}}{15}\, \frac{69049 x^2+1297462 x+2322769}{9675 x^2+96850 x+139427}$$ which, for an absolute maximum error of $0.01$ can be used up to $x=6$.

Comment: references would be useful

Comment: @jim. The last one was from me (easy). The first one is a Puiseux series; looking for it, I just found  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicCosine.html